# How to hide /disable reload button in confirm alert when try to refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working on project in that when i try to refresh page it will show popup 'Do you want to reload this site' in that i want Reload button should be disabled or it should not visible in popup box so how to do this below is my code
How to hide Reload button in this  alert?
[image]

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){   return  "are you sure want to"  });

</script>
```

Comment: You can not do that

Comment: That's not javascript. That is a function of the browser

Comment: @epascarello is there any alternate solution for that ,i need this urgently.

Comment: There is no solution to your problem.

Comment: Maybe email Microsoft, Mozilla, and Google to see if they will make an exception for you and release a new build for your application.

Comment: @LegenJerry seriously i need to prevent reload or else all data will be loss

Comment: What type of data? Can you save the page? File > Save

Comment: @LegenJerry form data will be reset

Comment: @MSp showing an alert to the user is a good enough warning in that case

Comment: You should look into saving data to Sessions

Answer (score 0):

For [`confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm), [`alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert), and [`prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt), you can not do anything with the buttons. That's designed in such manner to prevent the page from preventing the user to close the tab. That's a step done to prevent malwares and all sorts of bad stuffs.